# Conflict between jquery.multiselect and jquery.selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using **jquery.multiselect.js** and **jquery.selectbox-0.2.js** in my application for muti-select drop down and single select drop down.

I am able to use both the drop downs perfectly alone. If I have a page with both the drop downs, i am having an issue.
The issue is that , *the muti-slect dropdown does not close, on clicking outside*.There is no issue for single select drop down. So once i expand the muti-select drop down and click somewhere on the page, it does not close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery select box plugin has the below function

```
$("html").on('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();          
    $("select").selectbox('close'); 
});
```

I commented the e.stopPropagation(); line..Now on clicking outside, it invokes the buur method in mutiselect...Thats the close.. I understand that because of e.stopPropagation(), the close of mutiselect was not getting invoked earlier..

Answer (score 0):

**What does your selector look like?** Is your selector inclusive of `select` elements in general or just those that are multiselects? For example:

`$('select').multiSelect();`

would affect all `select` elements, including those bound to the selectbox plugin.

If you haven't yet, make sure your multiselect plugin is only affecting `select` elements with the multiple attribute:

`$('select[multiple]').multiSelect();`

It's likely that your selectbox plugin could be affecting the multiselect elements as well. You'll need to filter these selects from those with the multiple attribute. You can do this two ways:

1. Provide the single selects with an identifying class (i.e. `class="single-select"`), which is more verbose.
2. Use jQuery's `:not()` selector, like so: `$('select:not([multiple])').selectbox();`

Comment: The selector I am using is on ID .Like  $("#uniqueMutiDropId").multiselect();   And For the other drop down $("#uniqueSingleDropId").selectbox();

Comment: What about for your selectbox plugin? What is the selector for that?

Comment: For the SelectBox also  $("#uniqueSingleDropId").selectbox();

Comment: And you aren't seeing errors in your console at any point and time?

Comment: No..On debugging a lot, i could figure out that the close function of mutiselect(blur to be exact) is not getting called , while using both dropdows..On using only mutiselect in my page i am able to see the close functionality getting called

Comment: Considering the details (using unique selectors, both work individually, multiselect doesn't blur) I would venture to say that the selectbox plugin is the culprit and is likely swallowing your blur event due to a greedy event binding.

Not the best answer to the problem but there's nothing glaringly obvious in this case.

Comment: I found a fix...Been looking for some for two days now...Not sure whether it is the right one....Adding it to the answer section